# How to order rows in custom order when there are duplicates?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Can you order the rows of a dataframe when the names are duplicated? I have a dataset that is very large and I cannot rename all the duplicated variables, it looks something like this

| stat | value |
| --- | --- |
| c | 3 |
| d | 7 |
| a | 9 |
| b | 5 |
| b | 1 |
| c | 5 |
| e | 8 |
| f | 5 |

And I have to order the rows, alongside with its corresponding value, before exporting as an excel file (ie I need an excel with an exact format).

| stat | value |
| --- | --- |
| a | 9 |
| b | 1 |
| c | 3 |
| d | 7 |
| b | 5 |
| c | 5 |
| e | 8 |
| f | 5 |

Edit: Sorry seems like there is some confusion on the order for "stat" in the second example. For the purpose of this question, please assume there is no specific logic for the order of "stat" in the second example, except that it has to be ordered exactly like so.

For context, I need to export the dataframe formatted in an very specific order, there's no particular reason for it except it is company standard procedure.

---

Data:

```r
xyzzy = structure(list(stat = c("c", "d", "a", "b", "b", "c", "e", "f"
), value = c(3L, 7L, 9L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 8L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: I have trouble to understand the ordering logic in your second example. How should the rows be ordered?

Comment: If a letter occurs that has already been ordered, restart until the same thing happens again?

Comment: The second example is ordered in a specific way that I am unable to change (ie it is what the excel file need to look like) - hence it is not in a normal logical order a,b,c,d,e,f

Comment: Hm I'm not too sure what you mean by that Friede

Comment: I couldn't understand your order logic. Why second `b` (row 5) comes before first `e`?

Comment: I think since `b` occurs on row 5 for the second time, rows 1-4 should be ordered (containing distinct letters). The next chunk of rows to be ordered ist from row 5 until first occurence of a duplicate letter. That does not happen in the example data, i.e. there is no way to check if my understanding is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the ordering of `stat` is clear to me but I don't understand if there is any certain order of `value`.

Here is a solution using `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)

# n samples
n <- 400
set.seed(0123)

# create table
df <- data.table::data.table(
    stat = sample(letters[1:5], size = n, replace = TRUE),
    value = sample(0:100, size = n, replace = TRUE)
)

# set initial order
data.table::setorder(df, stat, -value)

# get position by stat
df[, i := seq_len(.N), by = stat]

# now order again
data.table::setorder(df, i, stat)

# remove the index
df[, i := NULL]
```

```
> head(df, 10)
      stat value
    <char> <int>
 1:      a   100
 2:      b   100
 3:      c   100
 4:      d   100
 5:      e   100
 6:      a    99
 7:      b   100
 8:      c    99
 9:      d    98
10:      e    99

> tail(df, 10)
      stat value
    <char> <int>
 1:      a     5
 2:      b     3
 3:      e     2
 4:      a     3
 5:      b     2
 6:      e     1
 7:      a     1
 8:      b     1
 9:      a     0
10:      b     1
```

However, if value should NOT be ordered in any specific way. Don't order by it originally

```r
# set initial order
data.table::setorder(df, stat, -value)
```

Should instead be:

```r
# set initial order
data.table::setorder(df, stat)
```

**Edit**

If you want to order stat non-alphabetically, this will get you that:

```
# n samples
n <- 400
set.seed(0123)

# create table
df <- data.table::data.table(
    stat = sample(letters[1:5], size = n, replace = TRUE),
    value = sample(0:100, size = n, replace = TRUE)
)

# add custom order
custom_order <- data.table::data.table(
    stat = sample(letters[1:5]),
    order = 1:5
)

# merge to table
df <- data.table::merge.data.table(
    df,
    custom_order,
    by = "stat"
)

# set initial order
data.table::setorder(df, order, -value)

# get position by stat
df[, i := seq_len(.N), by = order]

# now order again
data.table::setorder(df, i, order)

# remove the index & order
df[, i := NULL]
df[, order := NULL]
```

Where

```r
> custom_order
     stat order
   <char> <int>
1:      a     1
2:      d     2
3:      c     3
4:      e     4
5:      b     5

> head(df)
     stat value
   <char> <int>
1:      a   100
2:      d   100
3:      c   100
4:      e   100
5:      b   100
6:      a    99

> tail(df)
     stat value
   <char> <int>
1:      e     1
2:      b     2
3:      a     1
4:      b     1
5:      a     0
6:      b     1
```

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know there is a setorder function in data.table, my data is in a tibble but I'll transform it into a data.table. Also yes the value is ordered

Answer (score 1):

If I understand, the order wanted is the first occurrence of each stat, and then the next occurrence of each stat.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(stat = c("c", "d", "a", "b", "b", "e", "c"), value = c(seq(7, 1))) 

df <- df |> 
  group_by(stat) |> 
  mutate(order = cumsum(row_number())) |> 
  arrange(order, stat) |> 
  select(-order)
```

From

```
  stat  value
  <chr> <int>
1 c         7
2 d         6
3 a         5
4 b         4
5 b         3
6 e         2
7 c         1
```

To:

```
      stat  value
  <chr> <int>
1 a         5
2 b         4
3 c         7
4 d         6
5 e         2
6 b         3
7 c         1
```

Answer (score 1):

If the inconsistence on desired output, line 5, (as pointed by @metehanGungor), was just an accident, you can try this:

```
libray(tidyverse)

aux %>% 
  arrange(value) %>% 
  mutate(.by = stat, pos = row_number()) %>% 
  arrange(pos, stat) %>% 
  select(-pos)

> df
# A tibble: 8 × 2
  stat  value
  <chr> <int>
1 a         9
2 b         1
3 c         3
4 d         7
5 e         8
6 f         5
7 b         5
8 c         5
```